# serving images by id with imageresizer.net

Tags: asp.net, imageresizer

I keep a mapping in database between an ID and the filename of the image uploaded on server.

This is because I need to refer to images in HTML using an ID and not the actual filename on the disk (if image is replaced, it would be hard to have a logic which replaces the references to the new image).

So the solution I see is to have a handler which is getting the virtual image path based on the ID, and then redirects to this URL. This should make the ImageResizer.net to still work.

```
public class Image : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        int id;
        if (int.TryParse((string)context.Request.QueryString["id"], out id))
        {
           string path = ...  // get filename from database by id and append any other query params used by imageresizer.net               
           context.Response.Redirect(path); 
        }
        else
        {
            // return error response
        }
    }
}
```

Referencing the image:

```
<img src="/Image.ashx?id=1&w=100" />
```

My question is, am I doing this right?
I am thinking about issues like caching on the client. 
Also, doing an extra request with Redirect (but this one is really the least I am concerned about now).

Comment: Probably yes. You're not doing anything with the width-parameter being passed in?

Comment: I left it out for simplicity. I am worried about issues regarding caching on clients

Answer (score -1):

#### It works, but the redirect adds significant latency. If you don't have control over the HTML (which is where the URL *should* change when the file is changed), then your options are limited.

If you can work with your caching headers so the redirect isn't needed, you can use the `Config.Current.Rewrite` event provided by ImageResizer, or use a generic URL Rewriting solution to simply parse and lookup the filename.

This will eliminate a round-trip to the server - and remember, redirects are cached, so you'll have the same problem unless you solve your issue with cache directives.

Also, if you're hitting the DB for each request, make sure there's some kind of caching in place.

Comment: With Redirect as I expected I have cache issues in the webbrowser. If image is updated, it shows me the old image. This is unrelated to ImageResizer.net, but since what I am doing is not working I need to use something else. I will try now Config.Current.Rewrite you mentioned.

Comment: not sure where to add this event handler, I guess Global.asax.cs?

Comment: sorry, the Config.Current.Rewrite is not going to help me.

Comment: Config.Current.Rewrite intercepts requests to the actual image. This is after the current http handler (Image.ashx) computed the actual image path based on the id. I don't understand how could Config.Current.Rewrite help me, can you please give me an idea? Thanks

Comment: I'm suggesting you get rid of the HttpHandler if possible.

Comment: I am sorry, your ImageResizer.net is a great library but your answer doesn't help me at all with what I am trying to do

Comment: Dozens of users with the exact same needs use Config.Current.Rewite. If you want both aggressive caching and filename independence, you need to change the HTML. You can issue a redirect from the Rewite event if needed, but redirects are a non-no for performance.

Comment: I don't think you understand my issue. Like I said in the description, In HTML the images need to be referenced by Id and not by actual filename. This makes Config.Current.Rewrite handler not being called.

Comment: Config.Current.Rewrite gets called for any URL with an image extension. With a small change, you can have it called for all URLs on the site.

Comment: what is the small change I need to do?